# how can i add specific video clip to several clips Automatically

Tags: video, merge, directshow, splicer

I was wondering if anyone can HELP me cope with my Problem!
I want to add a specific video clip at the beginning of several clips(about 200 different video clips) , so using a simple video joiner is Not a good idea to do that(it takes several hours to choose files then...) , is there any Application which I load all of my video Clips in it , and then it Automatically merge my specific video clip with all of them one by one?

I have tested splicer Library but it takes a lot of time to merge two small size videos

Comment: Please explain more, What is your desire result ? you want to add a clip in other video (which is also combination of multiple clips) right?

Comment: In Fact , i've made about 200 seprated tutorial video clips , i want to add a specific video clip(as my signiture) at the beginnig of every 200 video clips , the result is 200 video clips which start with my signiture at the beginning of them , in common video joiner softwares i should just load my signiture clip and then my tutorial clip and merge them,  but it takes a lot of time for me to load them one by. I'm searching for a programe which do this proccess(loading videos...) automatically Thanks

Comment: late, but if you unable to find solution.. did you try AVAssetExportSession. its apple define  way to join video.